# Zip File .Net Framework 1.1

Tags: zip, .net-1.1

How Can We Zip A File In .Net Framework 1.1 Without Use Any Third Party Control...

Answer (score 1):

By coding everything yourself.
Or, if the MS J# runtime doesn't count as 3rd-party, [you could also use that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using just the .NET Framework, you can't.  This will be something that will be provided in some later version of .NET (not yet released from what I could tell).  However, due to J# being part of the .NET Framework, you can essentially use Java do Zip and Unzip files for you.  The details are described at this site: [Zip and Unzip Files in C# using J# Libraries](http://aspalliance.com/1269_Zip_and_UnZip_files_in_C_using_J_libraries)